# Laravel 5.4 Mail error on Heroku deployment

Tags: php, laravel, email, heroku

I have a Laravel app that I deployed in Heroku. I do not know how to configure the mail. This is what I did with the `config\mail.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'My App'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

I get the following exception.

```
SwiftTransportException:
    Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myemail@email.com" using 2 possible authenticators`
```

My `.env` is here, I searched this problem, but none of it worked.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your environments variable in heroku dashboard or using command line.

As far I know, heroku does not read variables from .env. Thus, Swiftmailer is using credentials in your config/mail.php not from .env file.

So it's attempting to us

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
```

instead of

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
```

Also, the error says `@email.com` instead of `@gmail.com` do you have a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

in Heroku go to settings , click reveal config vars button, and add config Vars as your .env file MAIL portion

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

it works fine in my case

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add all the  info to heroku setting your your project since heroku does not read that file

Comment: as its an older question versioning is relevant. Post version for which this applies when you tried this. EoR.